# plot_confusion_matrix() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

i want to plot a confusion matrix of my trained model but stuck when a i try to plot my confusion matrix. The no. of samples of predicted value and actual values are same the length of both parameters are same but it still throwing error

> TypeError: plot_confusion_matrix() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'

here is my code for reference

```
# downloading VGG16 model 
img_height, img_width = 224,224
conv_base = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='max', input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3))
# creating a model without freezing the layers of Model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Dense(nb_categories, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
    learning_rate = 5e-5
    epochs = 3
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("sign_classifier.h5", monitor = 'val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=tensorflow.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, clipnorm = 1.), metrics = ['acc'])    
    history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                                      epochs=epochs, 
                                      shuffle=True, 
                                      validation_data=val_generator,
                                      callbacks=[checkpoint]
                                      )
            Y_pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator)
            y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
            print("test data samples",len(test_generator.classes))
            print("predicted data samples",len(y_pred))
            print("Shape of Predicted Value",y_pred.shape)
            print("Shape of actual Value",test_generator.classes.shape)
            y_true = test_generator.classes
            cm = confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes, y_pred)
            print("Confusion Matrix",cm)
            plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels = category_names, normalize=False)
```

the output of above code is

```
  test data samples 47
    predicted data samples 47
    Shape of Predicted Value (47,)
    Shape of actual Value (47,)
 Confusion Matrix [[22  0  1]
     [ 0  9  0]
     [13  0  2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

[sklearn.metrics.plot_confuion_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html) requires 3 positional arguments `classifier`, `X`, `y_true`. So you need to pass your model as the classifier argument.

But there is another problem that will occur if you pass your model as an argument to the function, your model will not be recognized as a classifier. To work around the issue I have created a notebook that might help you out. Here is the [link](https://www.kaggle.com/mdmashurshalehin/plotting-confusion-matrix-for-tensorflow-model?scriptVersionId=63046076&cellId=16)

Answer (score 1):

Use this format:

```
plot_confusion_matrix(X =test_generator.classes, y_true = y_pred, labels = category_names, normalize=False)
```

Comment: after using your format it gives estimator error i try o resolve this issue by this `plot_confusion_matrix(model,X =test_generator.classes, y_true = y_pred, labels = category_names, normalize=False)` it gives an error  > ValueError: plot_confusion_matrix only supports classifiers

Comment: still your code doesnt have the model creation part like this `model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)`  model.compile will help to add the optimization parameters